# Writing A Regular Expression For Search And Replace Function In Dreamweaver

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver

I am trying to update hundreds of lines of comments in my php files. My editor allows me to use regular expressions to perform a search and replace. However, I don't know much about regular expression to write it. Please refer to example below.

```
Dump($Data1, 'Library_reports.php - Get_Filtered_InventoryReport() - $Data1');
Dump($Data2, 'Library_reports.php - Get_Filtered2InventoryReport() - $Data2');
Dump($Data3, 'Library_reports.php - GetFilteredInventoryReport() - $Data3');
```

to be replace with

```
Dump($Data1, __METHOD__.' - $Data1');
Dump($Data2, __METHOD__.' - $Data2');
Dump($Data3, __METHOD__.' - $Data3');
```

So basically, I want to search for

> 'Some_Alphanumeric_string()

and then replace it with a

> __METHOD__.'

Comment: Could you clarify what the expression might be? Describe what you want to match on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try: [A-Za-z0-9_]() it's nothing complicated here.

**Edit:**

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]+\(\)
```

StackOverflow eats my backslashes :)

Comment: You should escape `(` `)` unless of course you like matching everything.

Comment: Used the site http://www.phpliveregex.com/ using Marcin's example and it works perfectly.

Comment: I've posted this by my mobile and i don't know why webbrowser eat my backslashes :/

Answer (score 0):

Search with:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(\)
```

Replace with:

^ intentionally left blank

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, this search regex will do the trick:

```
\b[a-z0-9_]+\b\(\)
```

...assuming you do case insensitive search. (It's an option in the Dreamweaver search/replace tool).
Otherwise:

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+\b\(\)
```

Note: I've included the underscore in the character class based on your use of them in:

> "Some_Alphanumeric_string()"